# Cflags usage in makefile

Tags: c, makefile

I wanted to know the use of C FLAGS.In make file what does the below snippet means ?

```
CFLAGS=-00 -g 
${PROG}: ${OBJS}
${CC} ${CFLAGS} -o ${PROG} ${OBJS} ${LDFLAGS}
```

what does -00 defines ?

```
############# Target type (Debug/Release) ##################
############################################################
TARGET_NAME=telematics

CFLAGS=-O0 -g
LinkDebug=-g -Xlinker -Map=$(TARGET_NAME)debug.map
LinkRelease=-O -s -Xlinker -Map=$(TARGET_NAME).map
SUPPRESS_WARNINGS=-Wno-write-strings -Wno-builtin-macro-redefined
COMMON_DEFINES = -DA5N2 -DLINUX_SYSTEM -DCT_2
C___DEFINES =
CPP_DEFINES = -std=c++11 -D_GLIBCXX_USE_C99 -DUSE_IOSTREAM -DOM_NO_TEMPLATES_USAGE -DOM_NO_FRAMEWORK_MEMORY_MANAGER
ConfigurationCPPCompileSwitches= $(SUPPRESS_WARNINGS) $(COMMON_DEFINES) $(CPP_DEFINES) $(INCLUDE_PATH) $(CFLAGS) -c
ConfigurationCCompileSwitches=   $(SUPPRESS_WARNINGS) $(COMMON_DEFINES) $(C___DEFINES) $(INCLUDE_PATH) $(CFLAGS) -c

###### Commands & Flags ################
RM=/bin/rm -rf
MD=/bin/mkdir -p
CC=arm-linux-gcc
LIB_CMD=arm-linux-ar
LINK_CMD=$(CC)
LIB_FLAGS=rvu

######### Context macros ##################
```

My question here is to basically understand whether that -00 is for static analysis ? From make file i thinks its -00(two Zero )

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80657/makefiles-cflags

Comment: Possible duplicate of [makefiles CFLAGS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80657/makefiles-cflags)

Comment: I'm pretty sure its `-O0` instead of `-00` (the first zero is actually a letter O). Reading `man gcc` says `-O0 Reduce compilation time and make debugging produce the expected results.  This is the default.`. Could you post the full Makefile?

Comment: Please see the makefile in the updated data

Comment: you are right about -o0 .From man page, it says it reduces compilation time.So its not related anywhere to static analysis like cpp check right ?

Comment: **"i thinks its -00(two Zero )"** -- wrong. It is **"-(Oh)(zero)"** where ``-O` is the optimization level compiler flag and `Zero` specifies the optimization level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably are using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) as your C compiler (perhaps as a [cross compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_compiler)), and your compilation commands are run by `make`. So read the chapter about [Invoking GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html). `-O0` (that is a `0` digit at last) is for
an [optimize option](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html) which:

> reduce compilation time and make debugging produce the expected results. This is the default

I strongly recommend also enabling all [warnings](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html) so put

```
CFLAGS= -Wall -Wextra -O0 -g3
```

in your `Makefile` (if you want more [optimizations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler), e.g. for benchmarking purposes, replace `-O0` by `-O2` or `-O3`). The `-g3` is a [debugging](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html) option (to emit [DWARF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DWARF) debugging information for the [`gdb` debugger](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/), which you should use).

Notice that `-00` is *not* for static analysis! You could consider using specialized external static [source analysis tools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_program_analysis), like [Frama-C](http://frama-c.com/) or [Clang Analyzer](http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/). These tools typically run much slower than a classical compilation (but of course any compiler is doing *some* static analysis internally for optimization purposes).

Take also time to read the [documentation of `make`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/index.html) (and probably of [binutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/binutils/), for your linker). I am not sure you want to keep your `SUPPRESS_WARNINGS` line (it smells bad). You might perhaps also use [remake](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/remake/) (also [here](https://github.com/rocky/remake)) to debug your `Makefile`. Be aware that GNU `make` has a lot of builtin rules that you could see with `make -p` and that you should use. BTW, `CFLAGS` is known to some of these rules (so is a *convention* in `Makefile`-s about compilation flags passed for compiling C files).

Notice that you might, with great care and parsimony, add (rarely) some [pragmas](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Specific-Option-Pragmas.html#Function-Specific-Option-Pragmas) or [function attributes](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#Common-Function-Attributes) in your source code, for example to disable specific warnings or force optimizations (only on some very few *functions*).

Comment: CFLAGS is nothing related to GCC, it's the set of options `make(1)` uses by default when invoking the C compiler, being it GCC, PCC, CLANG, or other....  the same way you have LDFLAGS, YFLAGS, LFLAGS, FFLAGS, PFLAGS, for calling `ld(1)`, `yacc(1)`, `lex(1)`, `f77(1)`, `pc(1)`, etc.

Comment: Did I wrote that CFLAGS is related to GCC?

Comment: Well, you begun saying _You probably will be using GCC_ and don't mention anything about `CFLAGS`, which is standard in `make(1)` jargon.... you recomend about C options to be used when compiling but don't talk about how `make(1)` executes a default build command.  It's your answer, no more comments (-;

Comment: I wrote that the OP has to  read the documentation of make. I don't have time (or space) to explain make. The OP should learn it by himself

Comment: But the question itsels states: _Cflags usage in Makefile_, so, or you have misunderstood the question or something wrong is happening here :)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to [the answer by Basile Starynkevitch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49064624/1475978), I'd like to add:

> In make file what does the below snippet means ?

```
CFLAGS=-00 -g
```

The above assigns `-O0 -g` (make debugging information work as expected, and add debugging information, respectively) to the `CFLAGS` variable.

```
${PROG}: ${OBJS}
        ${CC} ${CFLAGS} -o ${PROG} ${OBJS} ${LDFLAGS}
```

The above creates a compilation recipe for the file named in the variable `PROG`, with the files named in variable `OBJS` as prerequisites. Note that the indentation uses <kbd>TAB</kbd>s, not spaces. (This forum converts tabs to spaces in code snippets, that's why you get spaces if you copy+paste the above to an editor.)

The way make interprets this, is as follows: First, all of the files listed in variable `OBJS` must be created (and new enough). Then, the command named in variable `CC` needs to be run, with parameters `${CFLAGS} -o ${PROG} ${OBJS} ${LDFLAGS}$`.

For example, if `CC=arm-linux-gcc`, `PROG=foobar`, `OBJS=foobar.o`, and `LDFLAGS=-lm`, then to generate `foobar`, make needs to first ensure `foobar.o` exists and is new enough, and then run `arm-linux-gcc -o foobar foobar.o -lm`.