# makefile error *** missing separator. Stop

Tags: linux, makefile

Would anyone indicate the root cause and the fix for the make file issue?
Building on Suse 12 SP2 x64 i got this error:

```
tony@linux-31cz:~/sandbox> gmake -f gnumake.sys
gnumake.sys:18: *** missing separator.  Stop.
tony@linux-31cz:~/sandbox>
```

I have this make version:

```
tony@linux-31cz:~/sandbox> make --version
GNU Make 4.0
Built for x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Copyright (C) 1988-2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

Below it is gnumake.sys where [TAB] is one tab char.

```
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------#
#     Common definitions, can be overridden in Platform specific part
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------#
CC                = cc
CCPP              = CC
LIB               = ar rv
CP                = cp
RM                = rm -f
MV                = mv -f
TOUCH             = touch
NEEDMOVE          =
CPP_NEED_C_SUFFIX =
GREP_SEARCH       = "^\# .* .*\.[ch]"
AWK_COLUMN        = $$3
AWK_COLUMN_CPP    = $$3
WD               := $(shell pwd)

%if %env (BUILD_PRODUCT_VERSION, 712) 
[TAB]export BUILDFLAGVER = -DBUILD_PRODUCT_V712
[TAB]export TSMVERSIONTXT =7.1.2.0
[TAB]%if %env (VERSION_BASED_OUTPUT,1)
[TABTAB]export TSMVERSION=$(BUILD_PRODUCT_VERSION)
[TAB]%endif
%elseif %env (BUILD_PRODUCT_VERSION, 812)
[TAB]export BUILDFLAGVER = -DBUILD_PRODUCT_V713
[TAB]export TSMVERSIONTXT =7.1.3.0
[TAB]%if %env (VERSION_BASED_OUTPUT,1)
[TABTAB]export TSMVERSION=$(BUILD_PRODUCT_VERSION)
[TAB]%endif
%endif
```

Comment: Use `remake -x` to debug your Makefile. See details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49064624/841108)

Comment: Is %if valid in gnu make? Looks like a autoconf file!

Comment: What is line on 18?  Usually this is the result of a spa ce used instead of a tab char.  Are you certain this is a tab not a series of spaces?

Comment: `gnumake.sys` is not a GNU Make makefile.

Comment: This is an Opus make makefile, not a GNU make makefile.

Answer (score 2):

In the given example the wrong syntax is used. The correct syntax will be such:

```
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------#
#     Common definitions, can be overridden in Platform specific part
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------#
CC                = cc
CCPP              = CC
LIB               = ar rv
CP                = cp
RM                = rm -f
MV                = mv -f
TOUCH             = touch
NEEDMOVE          =
CPP_NEED_C_SUFFIX =
GREP_SEARCH       = "^\# .* .*\.[ch]"
AWK_COLUMN        = $$3
AWK_COLUMN_CPP    = $$3
WD               := $(shell pwd)

ifeq ($(BUILD_PRODUCT_VERSION), 712)
        export BUILDFLAGVER = -DBUILD_PRODUCT_V712
        export TSMVERSIONTXT = 7.1.2.0
        ifeq ($(VERSION_BASED_OUTPUT), 1)
                export TSMVERSION=$(BUILD_PRODUCT_VERSION)
        endif
else ifeq ($(BUILD_PRODUCT_VERSION), 812)
        export BUILDFLAGVER = -DBUILD_PRODUCT_V713
        export TSMVERSIONTXT = 7.1.3.0
        ifeq ($(VERSION_BASED_OUTPUT), 1)
                export TSMVERSION=$(BUILD_PRODUCT_VERSION)
        endif
endif
```

You will be able to find the detailed description here: http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html

Comment: This will fix the immediate symptom, but probably the OP is trying to use a file which isn't a proper Makefile to begin with.